# Applying similar functions across multiple columns in python/pandas

Tags: python, function, for-loop, pandas

Problem: Given the dataframe below, I'm trying to come up with the code that will apply a function to three distinct columns without having to write three separate function calls.

The code for the data:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'],
    'days': [365, 365, 213, 318, 71],
    'spend_30day': [22, 241.5, 0, 27321.05, 345],
    'spend_90day': [22, 451.55, 64.32, 27321.05, 566.54],
    'spend_365day': [854.56, 451.55, 211.65, 27321.05, 566.54]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols = ['name', 'days', 'spend_30day', 'spend_90day', 'spend_365day']
df = df[cols]
df
```

The function below will essentially annualize spend; if someone has fewer than, say, 365 days in the "days" column, the following function will tell me what the spend would have been if they had 365 days:

```
def annualize_spend_365(row):
    if row['days']/(float(365)) < 1:
        return (row['spend_365day']/(row['days']/float(365)))
    else:
        return row['spend_365day']
```

Then I apply the function to the particular column:

```
df.spend_365day = df.apply(annualize_spend_365, axis=1).round(2)
df
```

This works exactly as I want it to for that one column. However, I don't want to have to rewrite this for each of the three different "spend" columns (30, 90, 365). I want to be able to write code that will generalize and apply this function to multiple columns in one pass.

I thought I could create lists of the columns and their respective days, use the "zip" function, and nest the function in a for loop, but my attempt below ultimately fails:

```
spend_cols = [df.spend_30day, df.spend_90day, df.spend_365day]
days_list = [30, 90, 365]

for col, day in zip(spend_cols, days_list):
    def annualize_spend(row):
        if (row.days/(float(day)) < 1:
            return (row.col)/((row.days)/float(day))
        else:
            return row.col
    col = df.apply(annualize_spend, axis = 1)
```

The error:

```
AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'col'")
```

I'm not sure why the loop approach is failing. Regardless, I'm hoping for guidance on how to generalize function application in pandas. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your two function definitions:

```
def annualize_spend_365(row):
    if row['days']/(float(365)) < 1:
        return (row['spend_365day']/(row['days']/float(365)))
    else:
        return row['spend_365day']
```

and

```
#col in [df.spend_30day, df.spend_90day, df.spend_365day]
def annualize_spend(row):
    if (row.days/(float(day)) < 1:
        return (row.col)/((row.days)/float(day))
    else:
        return row.col
```

See the difference? On the one hand, in the first case you access the fields with explicit field names, and it works. In the second case you try to access `row.col`, which fails, but in this case `col` assumes *the values* of the corresponding fields in `df`. Instead try

```
spend_cols = ['spend_30day', 'spend_90day', 'spend_365day']
```

before your loop. On the other hand, in the syntax `df.days` the field name is actually "days", but in `df.col` the field name is not the string "col", but the *value* of the string `col`. So you might want to use `row[col]` in the latter case as well. And anyway, I'm not sure how wise it is to take `col` as an output variable inside your loop over `col`.

---

I'm unfamiliar with `pandas.DataFrame.apply`, but it's probably possible to use a single function definition, which takes the number of days and the field of interest as input variables:

```
def annualize_spend(col,day,row):
    if (row['days']/(float(day)) < 1:
        return (row[col])/((row['days'])/float(day))
    else:
        return row[col]

spend_cols = ['spend_30day', 'spend_90day', 'spend_365day']
days_list = [30, 90, 365]

for col, day in zip(spend_cols, days_list):
    col = df.apply(lambda row,col=col,day=day: annualize_spend(col,day,row), axis = 1)
```

The `lambda` will ensure that only one input parameter of your function is dangling free when it gets `apply`d.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I figured my problem was conceptual, so thanks for outlining a more coherent plan. If you have the time, can you explain the arguments in the lambda function (row, col=col, day=day)?

Comment: @UncleMilton sure:) The lambda can only use variables that are explicitly passed to it, so you pass `col` and `day` to it. It's a lazy thing to name the lambda's parameters this way, probably this would be clearer: `lambda var1,var2=col,var3=day: annualize_spend(var2,var3,var1)`. So you set default values for the *last* two parameters of the lambda, thereby effectively rendering it a single-input function for `apply`. Since these are just default values,the lambda could also work in a 2 or 3-input syntax, but `apply` only uses a single variable, so it must have at most 1 non-default parameter.

Comment: :Wow, thanks so much for the explanation. One more (general) question: why pass a lambda into the apply function instead of just the function itself? That is why df.apply(lambda row, col=col, day=day: annualize_spend(col, day, row) instead of just df.apply(annualize_spend) ? What efficiency/value is gained from utilizing lambda functionality when the function has already been created? (I have seen this approach taken for much simpler functions, and was curious why invoking the lambda was necessary when the function had already been created). Thanks again, most helpful!

Comment: @UncleMilton try it without the lambda:) You should get an error that your function expects 3 arguments, and only 1 is specified, How should your function know what `col` and `day` are? The names in function definitions are quite arbitrary, as exemplified by my use of `lambda row,col=col,day=day: ...`, so the name of the variables in the function's definition can't help in any way (it only helps the programmer). So it's simply because `apply` expects a single-input function, which it then applies to the variable.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand: the use of a multi-argument `lambda` is your way of getting around the single-argument constraint of `apply`. And this approach can be generalized when wanting to apply **any** multi-argument function with `apply` or `map` or `applymap`. That is, first explicitly create the multi-argument function. Then specify each argument in that function as a variable in the lambda. Finally, complete the lambda by calling the function (along with each argument). Again, many thanks!

Comment: @UncleMilton exactly, that's the idea. I'm glad I could help:)